# Creating a rainbow like background

Tags: pixelmator

How would I create a rainbow like background like this in `pixelmator`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a rectangle and fill it with Gradient with any colors you want. There is Rainbow gradient included too:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your tip. Is there a way to make the rectangle exactly reflect an HSB hue gradient when the Saturation is 1.0 and Brightness is 1.0?

Comment: @Auser You just click on the color stops and choose any color you want - look at the updated figure